# Magento 2.2.3: cart page showing only "Estimate Shipping and Tax"

Tags: magento2, cart, magento2.2.3

In magento 2.2.3, cart page only shows the "Estimate Shipping and Tax" text. Is there any way to remove that text and shows cart items? But in view source, js contains the country list and some other data. And in the end, it seems script is broken.

```
<script>
        window.checkoutConfig =
```

[image]

Comment: php fatal error? I always uncomment `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in app/bootstrap.php to help me see errors while developing.

Comment: Could be a that a block is being included that doesn't exist. Could you check your errors logs?

Comment: Had the same. I accidentally edited a core file (inserted one symbol). I ran `bin/magento setup:di:compile` and it threw an error showing where everything went wrong.

Comment: In my case Paypal plus was the culprit i disabled it and it worked.
That is not the solution BTW but i thought i should share what I've found so far.